# How do I find a sequence of values with Python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I got a sequence of tones which describes a header of a radio transmission. I need to detect this header to fire the signal decoder function.

signal plot:
[image: signal plot]

This is a plotted list using

```
ax1.plot(range(len(inst_fr)),inst_fr)
```

Each tone has the same length and there are 9 tones in the following sequence (t1, t2, t1, t2, t3, t2, t3, t1)

What's the best approach to detect this header having in mind that

- it's a sequence of 9 tones
- there are 3 different tones
- each tone has the same length
- I'm using scipy.io for audio/signal processing.

I started an approach to detect at least one of the frequencies, say `1500` with a threshold of `50`.

```py
threshold = 50
freq = 1500
for idx,i in enumerate(inst_fr):
    if (freq - threshold) < i < (freq + threshold):
        print("%s \t %s" % (idx, i))
```

The problem here is that I got a lot of "false positives" (actually real positives). And I'm not really sure how to proceed on checking if the frequency +/- the threshold matches in a range of ~1000 samples

Comment: Do you have an approach that is not the best but works anyway?

Comment: initial approach added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could approach this problem with varying levels of complexity and dependability.

You could do a cross-correlation with an ideal list of samples (i.e. each is of the correct level at the correct time) and set some threshold to detect when the cross-correlation is high enough to your liking.

The easiest one I can think of is to find the average of a range of samples around the middle of each symbol period and ignore any outliers from noise (say > 2500, < 1250). For example you have a bit centered around sample 8000 or so, you could average 7900 through 8100 and find the nearest tone.